# How to attach multiple form-data fields with supertest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, supertest

I am performing integration test, I have a scenario where i have to provide fields in form-data. I can able to provide one key and file at .attach. in my case i have to provide five keys and values in form-data in the same request. how to achieve it?

[image]

sample code i have done to perform.

```
      const response = await request(server)
        .post('url for the request')
        .set({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        })
        .attach('key', 'file');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.field()` to add the other text-based fields (see the [docs](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#multipart-requests) for more details):

```
  const response = await request(server)
        .post('url for the request')
        .set({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        })
        .field('category', 'Product')
        .field('type', 'Image')
        .field('category', 'Product')
        .field('entity_no', '12354')
        .attach('file', '/path/to/file');
```